# How to install pgRouting in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: pgrouting, installation, ubuntu

I want to install pgRouting in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I added the respective repository (https://launchpad.net/~georepublic/+archive/pgrouting-unstable?field.series_filter=trusty) but failed to install the package in the terminal so far. Did someone encounter this before? Thanks for every piece of advice.

Comment: Solved. Here's a SE link in case someone faces the same problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/54268/why-arent-my-ppas-showing-up-in-the-ubuntu-software-center

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:georepublic/pgrouting
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-pgrouting
```

Now you should be able to add the extension to the database:

pgAdmin >> Databases >> "my database" >> Extensions >> New Extension... >> pgrouting

See this excellent tutorial for more details: 
http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/installation.html

Answer (score 3):

I installed it successfully on Ubuntu Trusty with the following
(Change the version of Postgres to suit your installation)

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-pgrouting
sudo apt-get update

psql -U user -d database
CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting;
```

Worked Fine..